# Use python pandas rows to create permutations to create all possible scenarios

Tags: pandas, permutation, scenarios

I have 5 sheets in excel with different parameters.

`history`

```
idx  history
1    1daybehind
```

`recorded`

```
idx   recorded
1     daily
```

`optmethod`

```
idx   opt         optmethod
1     backprop    x1
2     convex      x2
3     monte       x3
4     monte       x4
```

`optpara`

```
idx   optpara   
1     x1x2    
2     x3x4    
3     x1x4  
4     x2x3
```

`filter`

```
idx   filter   
1     x1>0    
2     x2>0    
3     x3>0  
4     x4>0
```

I want to create a permutation of the row entries so I want to end up with the following sheet with all possible scenarios. This is just the first 6 rows.

```
scenario history recorded optmethod optpara filter
1        1       1        1         1        1
2        1       1        1         1        2
3        1       1        1         1        3
4        1       1        1         1        4
5        1       1        1         2        1
6        1       1        1         2        2
...
```

So the first row, scenario `1` will be `1` 1daybehind, `1` daily, `1` backprop, `1` x1x2, `1` x1>1

I tried the following code,

```
for name,sheet in sheet_dict.items():
    print(name)
    if name == 'history':
        sndf = sheet
        sndf = sndf[['idx']]
        sndf = sndf.rename(columns={'idx':name})
    else: 
        sndf['key'] = 1
        sheet = sheet[['idx']]
        sheet = sheet.rename(columns={'idx':name})
        sheet['key'] = 1
        sndf = pd.merge(sndf, sheet, on ='key').drop("key", 1)
sndf.index.names = ['scenario']
sndf.to_csv('scenarionum.csv',index=True)
```

But I end up with this. I have the correct number of rows but each cell is just filled with `1`s.

```
scenario history recorded optmethod optpara filter
0        1       1        1         1        1
1        1       1        1         1        1
2        1       1        1         1        1
3        1       1        1         1        1
4        1       1        1         2        1
5        1       1        1         2        1
```

I believe the answer to this problem is a cross join but I'm not sure how I can go about doing it.

What am I doing wrong and how do i fix it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `idx` is the index of your dataframes:

```
indexes = [ data.index.tolist() for data in sheet_dict.values()]
```

else if `idx` is a simple column of your dataframes:

```
indexes = [ data["idx"].tolist() for data in sheet_dict.values()]
```

Generate all combinations

```
sndf = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(indexes, names=sheet_dict.keys()) \
                    .to_frame(index=False)
                    .rename_axis("scenario")
sndf.index += 1
```

```
>>> sndf
          history  recorded  optmethod  optpara  filter
scenario
1               1         1          1        1       1
2               1         1          1        1       2
3               1         1          1        1       3
4               1         1          1        1       4
5               1         1          1        2       1
...           ...       ...        ...      ...     ...
60              1         1          4        3       4
61              1         1          4        4       1
62              1         1          4        4       2
63              1         1          4        4       3
64              1         1          4        4       4

[64 rows x 5 columns]
```

**Update**: alternative methods

With `cartesian_product` from `pandas.core.reshape.util`

```
from pandas.core.reshape.util import cartesian_product

sndf = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*cartesian_product(indexes))),
                    columns=sheet_dict.keys()).rename_axis("scenario")
sndf.index += 1
```

With `product` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import product

sndf = pd.DataFrame(product(*indexes),
                    columns=sheet_dict.keys()).rename_axis("scenario")
sndf.index += 1
```

Comment: What about the column names and new index starting from 1

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly! is there any other way to do this purely in pandas without creating a list first? like with joins or cross joins only?

Comment: actually could you explain why you have to use multi index and from product together. I understand from_product creates a cartesian product but im not sure why we need to use multi index

Comment: I used `MultiIndex` because `from_product` is a class method of `MultiIndex`. You can do the same with `itertools.product` or `pandas.core.reshape.util.cartesian_product` (undocumented). I need list because it makes the code more simple and you have already the `sheet_dict`, so I use it.

Comment: if you have time, could you show me cartesian_product as well?